# Как на чистом JS запустить модальное окно в Bootstrap 5?

Tags: javascript, bootstrap

НЕ понимаю как.
Перепробовал вариантов кучу, но не выходит, что то делаю не так тупо

```
document.querySelector('.show-modal').addEventListener('show.bs.modal', function () {
         myModal.show();
        }
      )
```

и так

```
document.querySelector('.show-modal').addEventListener('click', function () {
            var myModal = new bootstrap.Modal(document.getElementById('exampleModal2') show);
            }
        )
```

не выходит. Туплю

Comment: `$('.modal').modal({show: true});` или используя атрибуты, на чистом js никак, это уже будут костыли

Comment: @InDevX там есть инструкции вроде

Comment: @СергейМишин буду знать. Да, в 5 версии появилась такая возможность, до этого был только jQuery

Comment: @InDevX 

 document.querySelector('.show-modal').addEventListener('click', function () {
               var myModal = new bootstrap.Modal(document.getElementById('exampleModal2'));
               myModal.show();
               }

           )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вроде так:

```
var myModal = new bootstrap.Modal(document.getElementById('myModal'));

myModal.show();
```

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/modal/#via-javascript

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Так а клик по чему? никто не отслеживает

Comment: Спасибо, вот так сработало

document.querySelector('.show-modal').addEventListener('click', function () {
               var myModal = new bootstrap.Modal(document.getElementById('exampleModal2'));
               myModal.show();
               }

           )